# Only grab new data from API using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

good morning,

I've recently wrote a programme to pull transaction data from stripe's API and save as a .CSV file so i can import all transactions into QuickBooks very easily.
It works well and I'm very happy with it. However every time I run it, it will grab every transaction which i will then have to go through and delete all duplicate data in QuickBooks.
What would be the best approach to make the programme only grab the newest transactions?
would it be to give python a date to work from, or would it be to check if the data is already in the .CSV file and remove it?

this is my code:

```
var = stripe.BalanceTransaction.list()
length_of_list = len(var)
number = 0


def get_customer_data():
    charge = stripe.Charge.list()
    length_of_charge_list = len(charge)
    global number
    while number < length_of_charge_list:
        order_number = charge['data'][number]['metadata']['orderNumber']
        number += 1
        return order_number


def get_transaction_data():
    count = 0
    with open('stripe_data.csv', 'w+', newline='') as csv_file:
        stripe_data = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=['date', 'Description', 'Credit', 'Debit'])
        stripe_data.writeheader()
        while count < length_of_list:
            if var.data[count]['description'] != "STRIPE PAYOUT":
                amount = var.data[count]['amount']
                description = get_customer_data()
                created = var.data[count]['created']
                date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(created).strftime('%d/%m/%y')
                stripe_data.writerow({'date': date, 'Description': description, 'Credit': amount/100})
                amount = var.data[count]['fee_details'][0]['amount']
                description = var.data[count]['fee_details'][0]['description']
                stripe_data.writerow({'date': date, 'Description': description, 'Debit': amount/100})
                count += 1
            else:
                count += 1


get_transaction_data()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this based on how you have set up your extraction system.

1. Every time you pull data, find and store the latest transaction date in a file or table or elsewhere. For every subsequent API call, send that date so the API knows to filter out transactions that are <= that date. Make sure you update the stored latest transaction date every time the API runs.
2. If you cannot have persistent storage like above, your API query can also go into QuickBooks and get the latest transaction date before it queries Stripe. In the same way as point 1 above, you just the latest transaction date to do a filter.
3. Similar to point 2, instead of querying QuickBooks, your API could query your latest CSV file for the latest transaction date (if you are storing these CSV files somewhere).

Comment: Thank you, I've done it as your option 3. set the last date as a variable pulled from the last .CSV and ignored everything before that date.